# How to get the compiler version in a post-build event?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, msbuild, post-build-event

I would like to add the version of the compiler to an auto-generated release notes file.

Currently, this is what I have:

```bash
echo "compiler version:" >>Release_Note.txt
MSBuild.exe -version >>Release_Note.txt

"echo "END." >>Release_Note.txt
```

When launching this post-build event, it fails with error 9009, most probably because the file `MSBuild.exe` is not found.

When taking a look at the possible macros, the only "programming environment" related one is `DevEnvDir`, which equals `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\` on my computer.

A quick search tells me that I have two files `MSBuild.exe` on my PC, located in these directories:

- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin
- C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64

Both directories are not child folders of the mentioned `DevEnvDir` macro, so I'm hesitant to use them.

Is there a `$Compiler.exe` post-build event macro, which I can use for launching the `MSBuild.exe -version` command?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want this number? It's an interesting request that I haven't seen before (I work on VS). You can get the C# language version you are targeting via the [`LangVersion`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/language#langversion) MSBuild property. But you could use a newer compiler to target an older language version. Do you reference the compiler explicitly via a NuGet package, or do you take the compiler from the SDK? Are you using SDK-style projects?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vswhere/wiki/Find-MSBuild

Comment: @DrewNoakes: I'm insterested in the version of the compiler, which is used for building my application. I believed this to be the `MSBuild.exe --version`, but maybe `dotnet --version` is more what I need?

Comment: That doesn't really explain _why_ you want that version, which I'm curious about. Regardless, each version of .NET ships a default version of the compiler, but you can also load your own version via https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers.Toolset/, for example.

Answer (score 1):

`MsBuild --version` returns the version of MsBuild, which is (more or less) related to the Visual Studio version. This is not the version of the dotnet (C#) compiler used. To get the .NET version that was used during build use `dotnet --version` instead (which will in turn report the version that was specified in your `global.json`, if it exists).

To call `dotnet` you don't have to search in magical paths, because that is available in the default path.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `where` command in the post-build event to find the location of the MSBuild.exe file and then execute it with the `-version` argument!

something like this :

```
echo "compiler version:" >> Release_Note.txt
where /R "C:\Program Files (x86)" MSBuild.exe >> Release_Note.txt
echo "END." >> Release_Note.txt
```